# Computing $P(X \leq Y)$ without Law of Iterated Expectation

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables such that $X \approx \exp(\lambda_1)$  and $Y \approx \exp(\lambda_2)$. Let $Z=\min(X,Y)$. Show that $\mathbb P(Z = X) = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$.

I of course wrote that $\mathbb P(Z = X)=\Bbb P(X \leq Y)$ but I don't know how to continue. The solution I was given says that since X and Y are independent, the joint density of $(X,Y)$ is given by $$f_{X,Y} (x, y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y) = \lambda_1e
^{−λ_1x}λ_2e^{−λ_2y}$$

such that $$P(X \leq Y ) = \int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \lambda_1 \lambda_2 e
^{−λ_1x}e^{−λ_2y}dxdy$$

I really do not understand why is this taken to $\Bbb R^2$ and most importantly with is the last equality true ?

I read this post [Finding P(X<Y) for exponential Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744266/finding-pxy-for-exponential-random-variable) that I think uses this post [Proving the identity $P( X + Y = a)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P( X + y = a)f_Y(y) \, \text{d}y $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217066/proving-the-identity-p-x-y-a-int-infty-infty-p-x-y-af-yy?rq=1) that uses "Law of Iterated Expectation" (I don't know about it).

Is there a way out that does not require this law ?

Comment: What is $Z$? I try to edit it and please see if that is correct.

Comment: @JetfiRex Very nice observation in fact, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why taken to $\mathbb{R}^2$: because you have two random variable, and you are calculating joint distribution of $(x.y)$

How to continue: just do the integral as it is. I don;t think you need to know about "Law of Iterated Expectation" since I don't know it too, but I can do that integration.

It is like

\begin{align}
P(X \leq Y ) &= \int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \lambda_1 \lambda_2 e
^{−λ_1x}e^{−λ_2y}dxdy\\
&= \int_0^\infty \lambda_1  e
^{−λ_1x}e^{−λ_2x}dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \lambda_1  e
^{−(λ_1+\lambda_2)x}dx=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}
\end{align}

Comment: Yes the calculations that come after are not a problem, I want to understand from where does the $P(X \leq Y ) = \int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \lambda_1 \lambda_2 e
^{−\lambda_1x}e^{−\lambda_2y}dxdy$ come

Comment: @Kilkik That is because the probability is taken of two variables $(x,y)$ so we have a space of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and since they are independent, the density of the joint distribution is the product of both densities. The integral just calculate the overall density of the events of $X\le Y$. Please let me know if you have further questions.